# What is the real and imaginary part of $(i+1)^{17}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hello i know that $(i+1)^{17}=256+256i$ is. But how do you get to that result?

Comment: The easiest systematic way IMO is to write $1+i$ in complex exponential form and then use Euler's formula.

Comment: To raise to a large power use repeated squaring, viz. $z^{17}=(((z^2)^2)^2)^2z$.

Answer (score 3):

$(i+1)^2=2i$ so $(i+1)^{16}=256$ and $(i+1)^{17}=256+256i$

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial expasion:
$$(1+i)^{17}=\sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k}1^{17-k}i^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k}i^k$$

Just use the circularity of the powers of $i$

Best way is using the polar form of the complex numbers:
$$1+i=\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}\implies (1+i)^{17}=2^{17/2}e^{17\pi i/4}=256\sqrt2(\cos(17\pi/4)+i\sin(17\pi/4))=256\sqrt2(\cos(pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))=256(1+i)$$

Comment: "Just use the circularity of the powers of $i$" is kind of hand wavy.

Comment: What do you mean? Im not english native speaker

Comment: The binomial sum that you simplified to takes a lot of effort to solve. It's not optimal at all. That being said, your other method is perfectly fine!

Comment: Oh yes, i only pointed it because i always like to give different solutions for the same problem. But yes it's to complicated compared with the second one hahaha

Answer (score 0):

$$i+1=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)=e^{\pi i/4}\sqrt{2}$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}(i+1)^{17} & =256e^{17\pi i/4}\sqrt{2}\\ & =256\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac {\pi}4+i\sin\frac {\pi}4\right)\\ & =256+256i\end{align*}$$